# Wrong link returned from Page.GetRouteURL() in WebForms 4.0 Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, routes, seo

I use this link in all my aspx pages, in order to retrive the right path( the same for js and img link)

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href='<%= Page.GetRouteUrl("~/myStyleSheet.css")%>'  type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

and it works, but just in one page I am obtaining the wrong path, if I check the HTML rendered it looks like this (it produce a 404 error message of course)

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href='/MyWebAppName/?Length=30'  type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

the codebihind contains as all my pages the right imports

```
Imports System.Web.Routing
```

why this behavior? what does `Length` mean ?
Thank you in advance

EDIT 1:
I forgot to say that the link I am clicking is inside the MasterPage

EDIT 2:
I found a temporary solution that I don't like at all and I have to check once I have deployed on the server to see if it works.

This is the path where I am:

http://shop.erricomaria.it/search/articles/

so in order to make the css work I wrote as follow:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="../../myStyleSheet.css"  type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I recognize that is really bad, but is the only solution I've found.
If you have a better idea please share it.

Comment: The EDIT 2 doesn't work properly I guess it is not recommended, I should use "Page.GetRouteUrl" but I am still trying to understand why it does not work. Any help? Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't work because you're searching a value for a route parameter called "~/myStyleSheet.css".

You need to set a route mapping inside the global.asax method Application_Start like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("MyStyleSheet", "mystylesheet", "~/myStyleSheet.css", true);
```

Inside your page replace your link code with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href='<%= Page.GetRouteUrl("MyStyleSheet", new RouteValueDictionary(new { }))%>'  type="text/css" media="screen" />
```